# Is code between ConcurrentQueue wait_and_pop and push thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, cpu-architecture

```
ConcurrentQueue.wait_and_pop(detector);
detector->detect();
ConcurrentQueue.push(detector);
```

detector->detect() is not thread safe.

1. Is the code safe in multithread env if ConcurrentQueue is implemented by mutex? Why?
2. Is the code safe in multithread env if ConcurrentQueue is implemented by lock free? Why?

Comment: Does `push` use a sequential-consistency release-store to publish `detector` to other threads?  I'm not sure if it's possible to implement a concurrent queue without that guarantee, but maybe with single producer / multiple consumers.  (Other consumers obviously couldn't re-queue after popping, but they could maybe pop it and run it before all actions of your call were globally visible.)  Not sure, I'm not ready to wrap my head around this enough to post an answer.

Comment: You tagged this `[cpu-architecture]`.  Did you have a specific one in mind?  Are you asking about C++ implementations on real hardware architectures (which give guarantees at least as strong as the ISO C++11 semantics your code uses, but often stronger), **instead of** pure C++ language rules?

Comment: @PeterCordes We use std::condition_variable.notify_one to notify other threads and our code runs on x86. It would be great if you could explain the behaviour under this env. Thanks very much.

Comment: On x86 every atomic RMW operation is a full memory barrier.  Any plausible queue implementation will thus have full barriers in pop and push, so the code that runs while `detector` is not in the queue can't reorder with accesses from other cores when they have `detector` out of the queue.

Comment: It's safe because it's guaranteed that only one thread exactly will unblock with instance of detector. I do not understand the question. It does not matter how ConcurrentQueue is implemented. Any implementation should guarantee this.